# Should You Still Subclass NSControl in 2018

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit

As of 2018, what is the correct way to create a custom control with AppKit/Cocoa?

The traditional technique has been to subclass `NSControl` and/or `NSCell` for the type of custom control you're implementing. (Such as an `NSButton` that does custom drawing.)

However, in WWDC 2014-204 Apple stated that `NSCell` is on its way to "Formal Deprecation". In WWDC 2012-217, Apple suggests subclassing `NSView` and taking advantage of layer-backing and layer properties to draw a simple button.

If you subclass `NSView` to create a custom control (such as a "better button") then you lose a lot of functionality that `NSControl` offers, such as pre-wired `action` and `target` properties, mouse-tracking, keyboard activation and probably a bunch of other things I'm not even aware of.

If you subclass `NSControl`, or even `NSButton`, what is the correct way to take over all of the drawing? [Apple's Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ControlCell/Tasks/SubclassingNSControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000730-BCIDJCGE) has not been updated regarding this. In particular, can an `NSButton` subclass just override all the `draw...` methods from itself and `NSCell` and then just do what it wants to do in `updateLayer`? Is there any guarantee that the existing `NSButton/NSButtonCell` drawing code won't still do any drawing?

What if you wanted to build a button with a custom background but still uses a string-based `title` or `attributedTitle`? `NSButton` offers this but how does the `title` drawing interact with `updateLayer`?

*My use-case is to create a custom button that offer more visual states and more visual designs than a traditional `NSButton`. Using a layer-backed `NSView` and `updateLayer` makes implementing all of the different states a breeze, but I'd prefer to subclass `NSControl` or even `NSButton` so that I also retain all of the functionality that those classes already offer.*

Edit 1: Changed wording based on comments below to more accurately reflect the current deprecation state of NSCell.

Comment: Where are you hearing that `NSCell` is deprecated? The release notes have been talking about their plans to _eventually_ deprecate it for years, but AFAIK they haven't pulled the trigger on that yet.

Comment: `NSCell` is _not_ deprecated as of 10.13. `NSCell` has been deprecated for use in `NSTableView` et. al. for years now, with the transition to `NSView` based tables and collection views. This is where you probably heard that you shouldn't use cell objects. `NSCell` is used by `NSControl` and every core Cocoa control (`NSButton`, `NSSegmentControl`, `NSDatePicker`, `NSSlider`, ...). So for now, `NSCell` is alive and well inside the `NSControl` family.

Comment: James, if you look at the bottom of `NSControl.h` you'll see that most of the cell related properties and methods have been moved into a category called "NSDeprecated". As well, in WWDC 2014-204, Apple makes a *really* strong statement that `NSCell` (and in particular when it relates to `NSControl`) is on its way to formal deprecation. That was four years ago. I agree that NSCell might not be formally deprecated today, but it's about as close as it can get.

Comment: @JamesBucanek The cell based table view is not deprecated. [NSTableView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview?language=objc) "You can still use NSCell objects for each row and column item if you prefer."

Comment: I have no doubts that Apple would like to move away from `NSCell`, but the reality is that every `NSControl` subclass is still built on top of `NSCell` and Apple has yet to provide a functional alternative. In the case of `NSTable`, Apple *has* provided an `NSView` alternative that we can use today. So in the grand order of things, I feel that `NSCell` for tables is "more deprecated" than `NSCell` for `NSControl`.